# Ответ сервера в Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Всем привет. Прошу помочь, почему метод getResponseCode() не показывает 301 редирект. Например сайты http://healthtian.com/ и vesti-ukr.com. Если их проверить на https://2ip.ru/, то у них 301 редирект. Если пробовать узнать код через Google Apps Script, то оба возвращают 200:

```
  var domain = "http://healthtian.com/";
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(domain);
  var response = result.getResponseCode();
  var headers = result.getAllHeaders();
  Logger.log(domain + ' ' + response);

  var domain1 = "vesti-ukr.com";
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(domain1);
  var response = result.getResponseCode();
  var headers = result.getAllHeaders();
  Logger.log(domain1 + ' ' + response);
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию редиректы включены. Отключите их в опциях запроса

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {followRedirects: false})
```

Пример

```
 var result;
 var response;
 var domain = 'http://contributor.pw/';
 result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(domain);
 response = result.getResponseCode();
 // var headers = result.getAllHeaders();
 Logger.log(domain + ' ' + response);

 var domain1 = 'http://contributor.pw/';
 result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(domain1, { followRedirects: false });
 response = result.getResponseCode();
 // var headers = result.getAllHeaders();
 Logger.log(domain1 + ' ' + response);
```

> [19-11-28 01:52:10:227 PST] http://contributor.pw/ 200
>   [19-11-28 01:52:10:529 PST] http://contributor.pw/ 301